# Passing parameters to predefined callbacks in Javascript/NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, bcrypt

I'm trying to extend my simple signin method of a NodeJs backend with `bcrypt`. My problem is that I now need to pass the `user` variable through the hashing step. My current method looks like this -- and naturally `user`  is undefined in the scope of `onPasswordHashed`:

```
signin : function(req, res, next) {
  step (
    function findUser() {
      User.findOne({ "email": req.body.email }, this);
    },
    function onResultReceived(error, user) {
      if (error) {
        ...
      } else {
        if (user) {
          bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, this);
        } else {
          ...
        }
      }     
    },
    function onPasswordHashed(error, hash) {
      if (error) {
        ...
      } else {
        bcrypt.compare(user.password, hash, this); // user is undefined here
      }
    },
    ...
  );
},
```

In principle I can: (a) Use the synchronous call of `bcrypt`. However, at some point I might encounter the same issue where no synchronous function call is available. (b) I can define `var userObj = null` at first and set it `userObj = user` in the `onResultReceived` method. `userObj` should then be visible in all scopes. But that doesn't seem to be a best practice. Or does it?

From reading up so far, using `bind()` seems the way to go. I just don't get my head around it how to apply it to my. For example:

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, this.bind({user: user}));
```

doesn't work. I don't know if the `step` package might cause any issues here. It's just very convenient to handle chains of callbacks.

EDIT: Links to `step` package documentation: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/step), [github](https://github.com/creationix/step)

From what I found and tested, I can overwrite the callback, e.g.:

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, this(user));
```

But with this I of course loose information about `error` and `hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an inline anonymous callback that can directly access variables in the parent scope of you can use `.bind()` to add arguments to the callback or in your particular sequence case, you can save the `user` object to a higher scoped variable so it is available to subsequent callbacks.   See the `localUser` variable in this example:

```
signin : function(req, res, next) {
  var localUser;
  step (
    function findUser() {
      User.findOne({ "email": req.body.email }, this);
    },
    function onResultReceived(error, user) {
      // save user variable to higher scoped variable so
      // subsequent callbacks can access it
      localUser = user;
      if (error) {
        ...
      } else {
        if (user) {
          bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, this);
        } else {
          ...
        }
      }     
    },
    function onPasswordHashed(error, hash) {
      if (error) {
        ...
      } else {
        // use localUser from higher scope here that was set by a previous
        // step in the process
        bcrypt.compare(localUser.password, hash, this);
      }
    },
    ...
  );
},
```

FYI, if you provide some info or link to doc on how the `step()` function works, there may also be a way to pass data from one step onto the next steps.

---

Assuming the `step()` function comes from [this module](https://github.com/creationix/step), you could also do it like this:

```
signin : function(req, res, next) {
  step (
    function findUser() {
      User.findOne({ "email": req.body.email }, this);
    },
    function onResultReceived(error, user) {
      // save user on our stepper object so it can be accessed by later callbacks
      this.user = user;
      if (error) {
        ...
      } else {
        if (user) {
          bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, this);
        } else {
          ...
        }
      }     
    },
    function onPasswordHashed(error, hash) {
      if (error) {
        ...
      } else {
        // use this.user that was set by a previous
        // step in the process
        bcrypt.compare(this.user, hash, this);
      }
    },
    ...
  );
},
```

The value of `this` as passed to each successive callback is a common function object that you can attach your own properties to.  While this sort of seems cleaner than the previous version, it's actually a little more dangerous because properties you add to the `this` object could conflict with things used in the internal implementation of the `step()` function.  The first option (an object in the parent scope) is totally private and won't have that possible conflict.

---

Now understanding more about how `step()` works, you can use `.bind()` to add the `user` object to the next callback arguments like this:

```
signin : function(req, res, next) {
  step (
    function findUser() {
      User.findOne({ "email": req.body.email }, this);
    },
    function onResultReceived(error, user) {
      // save user on our stepper object so it can be accessed by later callbacks
      if (error) {
        ...
      } else {
        if (user) {
          // prepend user to the callback arguments for the next callback
          bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, this.bind(this, user));
        } else {
          ...
        }
      }     
    },
    function onPasswordHashed(user, error, hash) {
      // user is passed in here from previous callback
      if (error) {
        ...
      } else {
        // use this.user that was set by a previous
        // step in the process
        bcrypt.compare(user, hash, this);
      }
    },
    ...
  );
},
```

Comment: Yes, using something like `localUser` reflects my alternative method (b) in my original question. I just wasn't sure if this is the right way to do. But you're right, I should check the `step` documentation. I was hoping I could could bind `user` in a simple manner.

Comment: @Christian - in your specific case, you can't use `.bind()` to pass the `user` because all the callbacks must be passed to `step()` before any have been run so the `user` object is not known at that time.  So, the alternatives are to save it in a higher scope as shown or to pass an object through to each callback via the `step()` functionality and just add properties to that object as each function executes making those properties available to all subsequent callbacks.

Comment: "...or to pass an object through to each callback via the step() functionality..." - can you clarify how this works, maybe my extending your answer. In any case, I'm fine with a higher scope variable. I just didn't know if this the "right" way and might cause any side effects.

Comment: @Christian - as I've already said, I'd have to see some doc for the `step()` function to know how it works.  Please add that info to your question.  That isn't something built into node.js so please explain where it comes from and provide a pointer to the doc on how it works and/or the actual code.

Comment: @Christian - Now that I understand the `step()` function better, I found a way to pass the `user` object directly to the next callback.  See my third option.

Comment: That works like a charm - testing your third option. Perfect, thanks a lot! Maybe as a last question: Are there any solid reason why one option would be better than another?

Comment: @Christian - as I said in the text, I think the 2nd option is the least desirable because of the possibility of property conflict.  Between the other two, I'd probably pick the first one just because it's simpler to see what is going on without having to understand the internals of how `step()` works, but that's just an opinion.